# File Type on xp_cmdshell queryout

Tags: sql-server, bcp, laravel-excel, xp-cmdshell

I have a client who generates some csv for me with xp_cmdshell.

The problem is that those files doesn't have the mymetype set correctly, because my application (and other mymetype checkers) says that the file is "application/octet-stream", and not plain text as it is supposed.

I'm using Laravel-excel with Nova. The field validation doesn't let the file upload because it says it is not a csv file.

As I've not worked with SQL Server, I don't know whats wrong in the sentence:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.TABLENAME" queryout "C:\FILENAME.csv" -T -c -C65001 -t;'

--EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
--RECONFIGURE
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
RECONFIGURE
```

If I open that csv with excel, and then I save it as CSV with the program, everything works great, so that cmd sentence must be problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Windows does not record or store a file's type anywhere but in the extension; there is no MIME type explicitly associated with a file. You should compare the file's contents before and after processing it with Excel with a diff tool to see what the actual difference in content is, which is the only thing tools can use to determine the type. Note that `bcp` has no true support for CSV, in that fields that need escaping (because they contain the separator, for example) will not actually be escaped, so it's quite easy to produce something that Excel will accept but other things won't.

Comment: The most obvious thing to point out in this case is that your "comma-separated file" is semicolon-separated. While custom separators are not unusual, most things that get fed CSV do expect a comma.

Comment: We had some troubles with the commas, which caused some rows having more columns than the others. We're going to check if that could break the upload in laravel-excel.

Comment: Note for your client, leaving xp_cmdshell enabled is a big security risk. If dynamic BCP statements are needed, this should be done through another method (SSIS, OS scripting, etc...)

Comment: Unfortunately, this issues was not resolved. We have still the problem. All the columns are fine, but all files exported (csv or tsv) are detected as "application/octet-stream"...